# Design a Rest API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, meteor

Firstly, I am new to web frameworks. We are using Meteor. 
I have a Students Collection:

```
Students = new Mongo.Collection('students');
```

Currently, we are defining a Rest API as:

```
// Maps to: /api/getAllStudents
Restivus.addRoute('getAllStudents', {authRequired: false}, {
    get: function () {
        var students = Students.find().fetch();
        if (students.length > 0) {
            return {status: 'success',count:students.length,data: students};
        }
        else {
        return {
            statusCode: 404,
            body: {status: 'fail', message: 'Students not found'}
        };
    }}
});
};
```

Now, There can be another API getStudentByName as

```
// Maps to: /api/getStudentByName by name
Restivus.addRoute('getStudentByName', {authRequired: false}, {
    get: function () {
        var obj = {};
        for(var key in this.queryParams){
            var val = this.queryParams[key];
            obj[key] = val;
        }
        var students = Students.find(obj).fetch();
        if (student.length > 0) {
            return {status: 'success',count: students.length, data: students};
        }
        return {
            statusCode: 404,
            body: {status: 'fail', message: 'Students not found'}
        };
    }
});
```

Currently I am accessing them as

```
http://localhost:3000/api/getAllStudents
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000/api/getStudentByName?name='abc'
```

I will have many more such API's for Students (Get, put, post, delete). Also, I have many more resources like Teachers, Classes, etc. For each there will be set of API's defined. Now, I want to design my API's in a neater way(I know this is very vague and unorganized). I want to eventually call them as

`http://localhost:3000/api/Students/getAllStudents` `http://localhost:3000/api/Students/getStudentByName?name='abc'`

Right now, I have a Student-api.js where I have placed these 2 API's and classes-api.js and teachers-api.js containing their own respective API's. But, that's just too unstructured.
Can "something" like namespacing be used? 
Any help is really welcomed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A REST API should not contain verbs. The verb is provided by HTTP.

```
// All Students 
GET http://localhost:3000/api/students
```

A possible way is to provide a filter param

```
// Students named Mark
GET http://localhost:3000/api/students?filter=name%3DMark

// Teachers whose last name is Johnson
GET http://localhost:3000/api/students?filter=lastName%3DJohnson
```

This is the beauty of REST APIs using a uniform interface. Now all your API calls can support the same filter parameter.

The following is a simple example for equality matching on a single field that probably needs to be adjusted since I haven't tested it. You can improve it to make the filtering smarter by supporting multiple fields and different operators.

```
var filterableCollections = ['students', 'teachers'];
filterableCollections.forEach(function(collectionName) {
    var Collection = new Mongo.Collection(collectionName);
    Restivus.addRoute(collectionName, {authRequired: false}, {
        get: function() {
            var items;
            var filter = this.queryParams.filter;
            if (filter) {
                var fieldNameValue = filter.split('=');
                var queryObj = {};
                queryObj[fieldNameValue[0]] = fieldNameValue[1];
                items = Collection.find(queryObj).fetch();
            } else {
                items = Collection.find().fetch();
            }

            var response; 
            if (items.length > 0) {
                response = {status: 'success', count: items.length, data: items};
            } else {
                response = {
                    statusCode: 404,
                    body: {status: 'fail', message: collectionName  + ' not found'}
                };
            }
            return response;
        }
    });
});
```

---

Note: `%3D` is the URL encoding of `=`

Comment: But then, how would the code for the same be written? Is there some specific design pattern to be followed? or any specific references that would help me to achieve the same.

Comment: This is a great answer! I intend to provide this support out-of-the-box in Restivus asap (it won't be until after the 0.7.0 release). I hope you don't mind if I use this code as a reference for that.

Comment: Just filed an issue in case you or anyone else would like to discuss support for this in Restivus: https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues/70. As promised, I used your code here as reference. Just a heads up.